# Неправильный проход объекта итератором

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть итератор for, который проходит объект с данными, который в свою очередь был создан из json:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "BKK": {
      "origin": "IEV",
      "destination": "BKK",
      "price": 7936,
      "transfers": 1,
      "airline": "FZ",
      "flight_number": 730,
      "departure_at": "2017-01-16T03:20:00Z",
      "return_at": "2017-03-08T12:10:00Z",
      "expires_at": "2016-12-29T12:07:13Z"
    },
    "DXB": {
      "origin": "IEV",
      "destination": "DXB",
      "price": 2378,
      "transfers": 0,
      "airline": "FZ",
      "flight_number": 728,
      "departure_at": "2017-01-12T14:25:00Z",
      "return_at": "2017-01-31T19:55:00Z",
      "expires_at": "2016-12-29T18:48:32Z"
    }
  },
  "error": null,
  "currency": "UAH"
}
```

Вывод происходит при помощи следующего кода:

```
for (var p in json.data) {
   pwf.append('<h6><span>' + json.data[p].origin + '</span></h6>');
}
```

Казалось бы, работает вывод верно. Но мне нужно выводить не все 10 элементов массива, а лишь первые 3. И тогда я изменил свой код:

```
var i;
for (var p in json.data) {
   i++;
   if(i == 3) break;
   pwf.append('<h6><span>' + json.data[p].origin + '</span></h6>');
}
```

И вот тут уже начались проблемы - выводится не 3 блока, а только один. Методом научного тыка я определил, что если выставит в условии цифру 4, то выведется два блока, а если 5 - три. Я долго не мог понять, что происходит, но после того, как перечитал документацию по `for()`, до меня дошло, что пока for доберётся до нудного мне объекта, то он встречает на своём пути ещё `Object` и `data: Object` и тратит на эту процедуру две итерации. **В связи с этим вопрос**: как можно **правильно** настроить вывод трёх первых элементов?

Comment: судя по коду условие _i == 3_ всегда будет `false` - потому что сравнение NaN с чем угодно - дает false. А `i` станет `NaN`, после первого же применения `++`, так как начальное значение - _undefined_.

Comment: Если же поведение отличается - значит переменная `i` задается где-то еще в коде. И ошибку надо искать уже там

Comment: Object.keys(obj) - пробовал ? и потом по ним пройтись ?

Comment: @Grundy добавил json-строку. Будут очень благодарен, если покажете мне, как парсить эти данные при помощи простого `for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)`

Comment: @Orange_shadow нет, не знаю, как это сделать.

Comment: `var i = 0;`  поставь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это никак не повлияет на работу вывода.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin с чего это? добавь весь json и проверим

Comment: @АлексейШиманский разница будет лишь в том, что будет выводиться не один блок, а два. Пусть разница и есть, но я по прежнему не получаю 3 блока.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Инициализировать `i` надо нулем хотя бы. Иначе начальное значение будет не числовым, а undefined.

И инкрементировать после  `break`, a не до.

```js
var json = {
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "BKK": {
      "origin": "IEV",
      "destination": "BKK",      
    },
    "DXB": {
      "origin": "IEV",
      "destination": "DXB",      
    },
    "DXB3": {
      "origin": "IEV",
      "destination": "DXB3",      
    },
    "DXB4": {
      "origin": "IEV",
      "destination": "DXB4",      
    },
    "DXB5": {
      "origin": "IEV",
      "destination": "DXB5",      
    }
    
  },
  "error": null,
  "currency": "UAH"
};

var i = 0;
for (var p in json.data) {
  if(i == 3) 
    break;
  
  i++;
  console.log(json.data[p].destination);   
}
```

Comment: Теперь я понял, о чём вы.`i++ `нужно было использовать не перед, а после `break;` Спасибо!

Comment: Инкрементировать надо было внутри `if`:) `if(i++ == 3) `

Comment: @Grundy имхо это не понятно.